# Arranging textInput elements in two or more columns in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, textinput

The Shiny GUI right now looks as in the attached figure. 
I would like to optimize the space and arrangment of the (>30) **textInput** elements in two or more columns in the **sidebarPanel**.

How do I set up two columns with the *textInput* elements - is there a table type I can use?

How to change *textInput height*, I can see that only 'width' can be edited?

How to optimize the textInput elements arrangment: i.e. distance between elements, font size etc?

[image: optimisation of textInput elements arrangment]

Answer (score 2):

The code shows a two column and 15 rows (30 textInputs) sidebar design. Basically, you write a function to generate UI for one row and then just call it again and again using `lapply` for however many rows you want. You can use this approach for any number of columns.

`output$test` shows how you can extract values from all inputs.

```
library(shiny)

textInputFUN <- function(uid) {
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
      textInput(paste0("par_", uid), label = paste0("par_", uid))
    ),
    column(6,
      textInput(paste0("par_", uid+1), label = paste0("par_", uid+1))
    )
  )
}

input_rows <- 15
input_ids <- seq(1, input_rows*2, by = 2)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        lapply(seq_len(input_rows), function(x) {
          textInputFUN(uid = input_ids[x])
        })
      ),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("test")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$test <- renderPrint({
      sapply(paste0("par_", seq_len(input_rows*2)), function(x) input[[x]])
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: because it turned out that I need at the end only 13 parameters I did it by hand but I used the 'fluidRow(column(),column())' idea, thanks!